# How to write if (n & 1)?

Tags: java

For an `int` type `n`, how can you recast the expression

```
(n & 1)
```

to compile in Java when used in an `if` statement? In C and C++ it compiles fine.

Things I've tried:

```
if (n & 0x1)
if (n & 0x1 == 0x1)
if (n & 0x1 == true)
```

but the compiler dislikes all these.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I genuinely have been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: The question lacks clarity: I only guessed that you're using this within an `if` statement or similar. `(n & 1)` is a valid expression in Java.

Comment: I'd guess (and it's a guess since I didn't downvote) that this (`n&1` resulting in an `int` and Java not implicitly converting `int` to `boolean`) is covered by most basic tutorials so a quick search might have been sufficient.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but with 3K rep, you can't go around saying "the compiler dislikes all these." It sounds like you didn't even read the error, because if you read that error "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean" that could/should have been enough of a clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember your operator precedences please!

`((n & 1) == 1)` will do it. (`&` has lower precedence than `==` so you need the parentheses.)

Java doesn't implicitly cast to `bool` (which C++ does), and the relationals don't evaluate to 0 and 1 as they do in C.

Comment: [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: Thanks @MarounMaroun: Now the OP should print that out and stick that on the door of their downstairs toilet.

Answer (score 2):

`(n & 1)` is an expression that returns either 0 or 1.

If you want to convert it to boolean (to use in a condition), use :

```
if ((n & 1) == 1) {

}
```

which would evaluate `(n & 1) == 1` to `true` if `(n & 1) == 1`.

Comment: `if ((n & 1) == 1)` does not evaluate to anything, because `if` is a statement. Just `(n & 1) == 1` however, evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @marstran I guess I should have included braces to make it clearer.

Comment: The thing is, if you want to "convert" it to a boolean, you use `boolean b = (n & 1) == 1`. You don't need an if-statement.

Comment: @marstran You are nitpicking. The only purpuse of the if statement was to demonstrate how this expression could be used, since writing `(n & 1) == 1` by itself wouldn't pass compilation. Yes, I could have assigned this expression to a boolean variable instead, but figured the usage of a boolean expression in a condition is more common than assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the expression, except it needs to be assigned or otherwise used in a statement or you will get "error: not a statement".

The result of the expression is an `int`, so this works for example:

```
int x = (n & 1);
```

Comment: Is the purest answer until the OP finally clarified; plus one.